# Typescript - Promises. Async-Await for calls dependents on another call

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to improved the performance of loading data by executing requests in parallel or any other possible way. I'm new to Javascript / Typescript way of coding. I'm coming from Java.
Recently, I found about Async-Await and Promises.

I have two methods. 1st one is independent and executes only one request. 2nd is dependent to another requests' output value (in this case "number" value).

I am calling these function in this sequence.

```
private run(): void {
    this.populatePostTextData(list, 3);
    this.populateCustomerNameData(list, 5);
}
```

Below are my concerns:

Both doesn't seem to run in parallel/simulaneously. It waits for `populatePostTextData()` to finish (then sets value to DOM), then `populateCustomerNameData()` (sets value again to DOM)

The 2nd method has 2 requests. I don't know how else to structure the `await`. I tried to chain them

```
await Service.Current.executeRequest(getNumber).then((response: Response) => {
    number = response.items[0]["CustomerNumber"];
    console.log("Customer No retrieved: " + number);
    await Service.Current.executeRequest(getNumber)... 
}).catch((response: Response) => {
    console.log("Error: " + response.errorMessage);
});
```

But I get an error on `await Service.Current.executeRequest(getNumber)...`  that it must be within async because it's nested. It doesn't seem to read it as contained within an async method

1st Method

```
    async populatePostTextData(list: IList, columnNum: number) {
        const columnId = "C" + columnNum;
        for (let i = 0; i < list.getData().getLength(); i++) {
            let referenceOrderNo = list.getData().getItem(i).C1;
            let referenceOrderLine = list.getData().getItem(i).C2;
    
            const request = new Request("...");
            let postTextData = {};
            await Service.Current.executeRequest(request).then((response: Response) => {
                let postText = response.items[0]["PostText"];
                postTextData[columnId] = postText;
                postTextData["id_" + columnId] = "R" + (i + 1) + columnId;
                $.extend(list.getData().getItem(i), postTextData);
            }).catch((response: Response) => {
                console.log("Error: " + response.errorMessage);
            });
        }
    }
```

2nd Method
`getNumber` should execute first because variable `number` is used for `getName`

```
    async populateCustomerNameData(list: IList, columnNum: number) {
        const columnId = "C" + columnNum;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < list.getData().getLength(); i++) {
            let referenceOrderNo = list.getData().getItem(i).C1;
            let referenceOrderLine = list.getData().getItem(i).C2;
    
            let number = "";
            const getNumber = new Request(".../");
            await Service.Current.executeRequest(getNumber).then((response: Response) => {
                number = response.items[0]["CustomerNumber"];
                console.log("Customer No retrieved: " + number);
            }).catch((response: Response) => {
                console.log("Error: " + response.errorMessage);
            });
    
            let customerName = {};
            const getName = new Request("...");
            getName.setParam(1,number);
            await Service.Current.executeRequest(getName).then((response: Response) => {
                const name = response.items[0]["CustomerName"];
                customerName[columnId] = name;
                customerName["id_" + columnId] = "R" + (i + 1) + columnId;
                $.extend(list.getData().getItem(i), customerName);
            }).catch((response: Response) => {
                console.log("Error: " + response.errorMessage);
            });
        }
    }
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion or solution

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the second requests depends on the first one resolving since you have to pass in the number. In that case you could try something like:

```
const runner = async() => {
    try {
    const response = await firstRequest();
    // At this point you can assume that the first request is completed successfully and you can extract what you need from the response.
    const number = response.number 
    await secondRequest(number);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error):
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke `runner` or whatever you would like to call it whenever you need to kick off this process. The two request functions must return promises, or be async functions themselves which implicitly return promises.

You can also use the `.then` keyword, or the `await` keyword to organize the flow of your async parts of your program. Using them both is also possible, but typically you would see one or the other. If you wanted to use `.then` you could do something like:

```
const runner = () => {
    firstRequest()
      // get the number from the first response
     .then((res) => res.number))
     .then((num) => secondRequest(num))
     .catch((error) => console.log(error)):
}
```

await is the newer syntax though, so i'd probably recommend that. It makes the code a lot more readable as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything blocking the second function from running, but what I can see is your requests within their respective **for loops** being blocked by `await`. You should consider using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or removing `await` for calls you want to execute in parallel.

This sample code should highlight the behaviours you need to understand in order to understand *almost* everything about Promises and Async/Await.

```js
let hrstart = process.hrtime();

function time() {
    return `${process.hrtime(hrstart)[0]}s`;
}

function wait(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(time);
        }, time * 1000);
    });
}

async function blocking() {
    for (let index = 5; index < 10; index++) {
        let complete = await wait(index);
        console.log('blocking', complete, time());
    }
}

async function single() {
    let complete = await wait(2);
    console.log('single:', complete, time());
}

async function nonBlocking() {
    let jobs = [];
    for (let index = 5; index < 10; index++) {
        jobs.push(wait(index));
    }
    return Promise.all(jobs).then((res) => {
        for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
            console.log('non-blocking:', res[index], time());
        }
    });
}

blocking();
single();
nonBlocking();
```

Results in the following output:

```
single: 2 2s
blocking 5 5s
non-blocking: 5 9s
non-blocking: 6 9s
non-blocking: 7 9s
non-blocking: 8 9s
non-blocking: 9 9s
blocking 6 11s
blocking 7 18s
blocking 8 26s
blocking 9 35s
```